# DblClickZoom disable

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

Здравствуйте.

Собственно не отключается зум по двойному клику кнопок мыши:

```
  map.behaviors.disable([
    'drag', 
    'rightMouseButtonMagnifier', 
    'ClickZoom',
    'scrollZoom', 
    'DblClickZoom'
  ]);
```

Есть решение как отключить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript чувствителен к регистру, название поведения нужно указывать с маленькой буквы `dblClickZoom`.

Comment: Глупая ошибка с моей стороны. Спасибо )